# Why is the movie titled "She's Out of My League"?

Tags: title, shes-out-of-my-league

I didn't understand what this movie title means *She's Out of My League*?

*Synopsis*: Average looking Boy fallen in love with hot girl who has webbed feat.
They broke up suddenly just before making love & reunited at airport finally.

Comment: This is an expression to say she's way too beautiful for him. It's like she plays in a major sports league and he plays in a minor league.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20does%20she%27s%20out%20of%20my%20league%20mean%3F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=out%20of%20my%20league), the expression "She's Out of My League" means:

> Not the person that would date me.
>   Someone I don't have a chanche with.

In the movie, Kirk is average looking "a 5 in a scale of attractiveness" and Molly is beautiful "a 10 in a scale of attractiveness", so Kirk and his friend Stainer think he has no chance to seduce her.